# How to determine actual content width within div?

Tags: jquery, css

I want to make a `scroll` listener that will change a border once the user has scrolled all the way to the right. Below is a fiddle I created that hardcodes the value. I'm wondering how to determine that value programatically.

http://jsfiddle.net/C58VH/

HTML:

```
<div class="big">
    <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque auctor aliquet turpis et elementum. Etiam hendrerit scelerisque porttitor. In semper adipiscing tincidunt. Suspendisse in posuere augue. Ut aliquet feugiat dapibus. Ut vestibulum, odio id eleifend mattis, ipsum risus auctor est, quis feugiat neque nibh a lorem. Nunc iaculis nibh id ligula bibendum pulvinar. Sed id quam neque, scelerisque dignissim mi. Etiam ultrices erat sed mi scelerisque auctor at id lectus. Etiam vulputate quam eu diam ullamcorper a vehicula dui tincidunt. Proin a libero lectus.
    </p>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.big {
    width: 300px;
    height: 200px;
    overflow: scroll;
    white-space: nowrap;
    border-right: 1px solid black;
}
```

JS:

```
$('.big').on('scroll', function()
{
  if  ($(this).scrollLeft() == 3326)
      $(this).css('border-right', 'none');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not perfect yet I supose, but might help

```
$('.big').on('scroll', function()
{
    if  ($(this).scrollLeft() + $(this).width() >= $(this)[0].scrollWidth){
      $(this).css('border-right', 'none');
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/C58VH/2/